# clang: error: unknown argument: '-fno-leading-underscore'

Tags: c++, macos, terminal, g++, clang++

I am trying to compile my .cpp with -fno-leading-underscore option but it raises an error saying:

`clang: error: unknown argument: '-fno-leading-underscore'`

```
g++ -m32 -fno-use-cxa-atexit -nostdlib -fno-builtin -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions -fno-leading-underscore -o kernel.o -c kernel.cpp
```

How can I fix this I am new to Mac it used to work on Linux Mint

Comment: It seems, clang doesn't support this option

Comment: Does `g++ --version` say you are using clang?  Or have you installed the GCC compiler (e.g., `brew install gcc`)?

Comment: I tries this with gcc and g++ the result is the same. The reason I do not want to remove the -fno-leading-underscore is that the application consists of various file and not only c++ but also assembler when I remove -fno-leading-underscore it will require so many files to be updates

Comment: I installed GCC complier with brew install gcc

Comment: @OmerOzhan have a look at: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.0/gcc/Code-Gen-Options.html#index-fleading_002dunderscore-1989. `Warning: the -fleading-underscore switch causes GCC to generate code that is not binary compatible with code generated without that switch. Use it to conform to a non-default application binary interface. **Not all targets provide complete support for this switch.**`

Comment: on MacOS `g++` is just `clang` underneath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your terminal, type `g++` and press enter. You will probably get:

```
$ clang: No input files
```

As you can see its still clang underneath.

To fix this, first `cd` into `/usr/local/bin` and type `ls`. You will see the binaries inside:

```
g++-9
...
```

Next, create a symlink to it so that you can invoke `g++` directly

```
ln -s g++-9 g++
```

If it still doesn't work for some reason, you can explicitly write `g++-9` or whatever version you have. You can even give the full path `/usr/local/bin/g++-9`

Comment: I did those and know I am getting this errors with every file I cannot compile anything now.

Comment: I tried complying with many different scripts and got various errors.                        error: 'z\U000000a0' was not declared in this scope
   41 |             std::cout << x << "\t" << y << "\t" << z << "\t" << std::endl;                              error: 'template\U000000a0' does not name a type
  286 | template <typename T>                                                                                        /var/folders/mg/01wpmmzn4nv8bxxv3_3yyxfm0000gn/T//ccniavkq.s:228:2: error: instruction requires: Not 64-bit mode
        pushl   %eax

Comment: All of those are on different files

Comment: Did you confirm that you are actually running gcc now? As for the errors, they are related to your hardware. You need to ask another question for this :)

Comment: If your original question is answered, please accept the answer :)